# Rails Active Admin-I want to show selected members in my active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have User table and a Member Table. I am creating a Community i.e. another model community. While creating Community I am selecting Users and data is saved in Member Table but when I edit the community the selected members are not visible.

Community Active Admin file has code :

```
f.input :members, :as => :select2_multiple, :collection => User.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.screen_name, p.id ] }, include_blank: false
```

I am overriding the update action of controller.

Comment: Post full form code to have a better look at the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript on edit page write following script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $( "#dropdown" ).select2().select2('val',<%= @group.collect(&:members) %>)
  </script>
```

Replace @group with your own instance